# WCF Socket Error 10045

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, wcf

My colleague has an app that hosts a simple WCF service with a net.tcp endpoint.  I can add the service reference to any app I create using the address net.tcp://192.168.0.22:9999/GSS-POS/QueryDispatcher/mex

However, when he tries to add the service reference to an app running on his machine he immediately gets a socket error 10045.  We've tried using both net.tcp://localhost:9999/GSS-POS/QueryDispatcher/mex

and

net.tcp://192.168.0.22:9999/GSS-POS/QueryDispatcher/mex

He's tried re-installing Visual Studio 2008, Service Pack 1 and XP Service Pack 3 all to no avail.  Can anybody provide any pointers?

UPDATE: This appears as though it is related to Visual Studio.  By using the WCF Client test app, it is possible to see the service.  It seems as though VS is having the problem adding the service reference.

UPDATE 2: Adding a reference with VS 2008 works with named pipe and http transport.  The problem only manifests itself when trying to add a service reference which utilises a net.tcp endpoint.

Best regards,

Simon

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for you, but the code 10045 represents WSAEOPNOTSUPP (operation not supported) which, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668(VS.85).aspx), means:

> The attempted operation is not
>   supported for the type of object
>   referenced. Usually this occurs when a
>   socket descriptor to a socket that
>   cannot support this operation is
>   trying to accept a connection on a
>   datagram socket.

Answer (score 0):

The [book by Juval Lowy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526997) says that tcp communications are "optimised" for WCF->WCF comms only. Maybe that has something to do with your problem.